# Physical explanation for currents being inversely proportional in transformer windings

Tags: transformer, performance

Okay, so we all know that P=V*I, so in a step-up transformer the secondary windings will carry less current and still have higher voltage. The formula explains it conveniently. That does not make me understand it, though :-)

So if we are pushing the electrons along with higher voltage on a power line, what is it that does not allow more throughput? I suspect the secondary winding acts as a kind of resistor(?)

Comment: Seriously do you want us to write a 5 page description of how transformers work when there are tons of documents on line.... like this one... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer

Comment: Start looking at magnetic laws, yes the secondary winding changes voltage in the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic issue is that moving electrons produce magnetic flux.  The greater the number of turns in a transformer winding, the more magnetic flux will be induced for any level of current.  When the flux produced by the primary exceeds that produced by the secondary, it will accelerate electrons in the secondary until that is no longer the case.  The more windings there are in the secondary, the less current will need to flow to balance out the flux from the primary.

Answer (score 1):

Its conservation of energy. You applied some amount of power in the primary of the coil then if in the secondary both voltage and current increased then the amount of power increases meaning somehow you have over 100% efficiency or in order words it would mean energy is being created.

But in transformer we know that power in equals power out (neglecting all losses) so if you think about it to keep power constant then if the voltage increase then the current must decrease in order to keep you from violating energy conservation.

Comment: Sure, I just don't see how nature achieves this in this case. We have higher voltage so it must somehow be able to limit the current (to comply with the conservation of energy). The only way higher voltage does not lead to higher current is if somehow resistance increases.

Comment: No, you are trying to apply Ohm law in a case where it is not applicable. V=IR only applies to a resistive type element. With a transformer you are dealing with inductive elements having energy transfer over a magnetic coupling the limiting factor will always the the energy transfer through the magnetic fields.

Comment: @Kvegaroo Yes, that's what I was suspecting. The magnetic inductive elements are to blame here :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to see what's happening in a perfect transformer. As we let the core permeability become very very large, we find the magnetic field strength we need to drive a decent flux through the core, and hence the magnetising current we need to produce that, drops away to almost nothing.

Which then only leaves us with load currents.

The magnetic field strength is the difference of the load currents multiplied by the number of turns, N, in the respective windings. As the magnetic field strength approaches zero, the currents ratio approaches the turns ratio N. To give a concrete example, if we had 1000 turn primary, and 100 turn secondary, and 1A in the secondary, we would need 0.1A in the primary (or 1/10th the secondary current) to get the same 100AT (ampere.turns) in each winding, so that the difference would be roughly zero.

For voltage, the change of flux in the core generates a specific number of volts per turn in any winding. So our 1000 turn winding has 10x the voltage across it that the 100 turn winding does.

When we equate the power, 10x the voltage and 1/10th times the current, same power.

In a real transformer, there is a slight difference between primary and secondary ampere.turns that generates enough magnetic to drive sufficient flux through the core. But this is a fairly small effect.